# Intellij opens Dartium in checked mode

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, dartium

When I open Dartium from Intellij, it opens in checked mode. I can verify the environment variable `DART_FLAGS=--checked` with `ps eww <PID>`. I do not have this setting/variable set anywhere in Intellij settings that I can find. Why is the environment variable being set and how do I turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the discussion in the following request:

- [WEB-24466](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24466) 'Start Dartium in checked mode` option removed from project settings

tl;dr: the option was removed because this tool is used for development and running in checked mode helps to find the errors easier, there is still a hacky way to disable it:

Open [CONFIG](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519)`/options/web-browsers.xml` file and remove the following line from there:

```
<entry key="DART_FLAGS" value="--checked" />
```

Note that it may return back when you change anything in the Dart page in Settings, you'll have to remove the line again.